# How to validate Dynamic key -> value DTO validation in nest js?

Tags: nestjs

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export class TestDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  test: string;
}

export class UserReqDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  id: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  data: object;
}

const sampleData = {
  id: 'asbd',
  data: {
    ['any dynamic key 1']: {
      test: '1',
    },
    ['any dynamic key 2']: {
      test: '2',
    },
  },
};
```

Here `UserReqDto` is my main DTO and `TestDto` is child DTO.
I need to validate `sampleData` type of data.

How can I do that?

in data field i need to validate object of `TestDto` type's objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map<string, TestDto>` as type for `data` field:

```
@ApiProperty()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
data: Map<string, TestDto>
```

**Note:** Nested object must be an instance of a class, otherwise `@ValidateNested` won't know what class is target of validation so you can use `class-transformer` to transform data value to instance of `TestDto`.

```
@ApiProperty()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => TestDto)
data: Map<string, TestDto>
```